# READ CSV from DROPBOX

Tags: pandas, dataframe, dropbox

I have a program that takes input from a CSV that is in my colleague's dropbox at a certain URL and builds a dataframe. The program starts like this:

```
df=pd.read_csv('www.dropbox.com/s/certainurl=1')
```

I know that you have to put dl=1 otherwise it doesn't work but as I try to run the program it did see the CSV but it downloads data in a confusing way and subsequently, it cannot read the columns. Of course, if I download the CSV and I run the program taking the CSV from local all works perfectly.

I don't have Dropbox and looking in similar question on StackOverflow no answers fits.
How to solve it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

FWIW the problem was that my colleague saved the file as a particular CSV that uses ";" instead of "," to separate values. So I fixed with:

```
df=pd.read_csv('www.dropbox.com/s/certainurl=1', sep=";")
```

and the program worked.